# IDEA: Conditional breakpoint not to be hit in specified call context

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints

Is there a way to put a conditional breakpoint which won't be hit when the method the breakpoint is in is called from other specified method?

(I'm using IDEA 9.0.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature for the conditional breakpoints, however you can achieve similar behavior by using the breakpoint dependencies.

> Here you can set a breakpoint the
>   current one will depend on. Thus the
>   dependent, slave breakpoint is
>   conditionally disabled - it becomes
>   enabled only if the master breakpoint
>   is hit. Moreover, after the dependent
>   breakpoint is hit, it becomes disabled
>   again until the master is hit next
>   time. Hence you can form cascades of
>   dependent breakpoints to satisfy any
>   requirements. This feature works with
>   all other conditions, filters, etc.

Comment: Looks like a nice feature, though in the case I needed it it would be more convenient to use an exclusive approach so that the breakpoint is not hit when the method is called from within a certain method and it is hit in all other cases. It might work with the dependency feature if it disabled the slave breakpoint when the master breakpoint is hit and re-enabled it afterwards.